# Docker Maven plugin: how to specify shm size when running a container

Tags: maven, docker

I'm currently using [fabric8io Docker Maven Plugin](https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin), version 0.15.1, and I need to specify the shm size when running a container, as described in Docker reference documentation here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

And I don't how to specify this option in the Maven Docker plugin: any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the plugin does not have the option shm-size mapped into their code see their user manual: https://fabric8io.github.io/docker-maven-plugin/docker-start.html

You should fill an **issue** to ask them to add this option, or if you're brave enough, implement that and submit a **PR**.

Answer (score 0):

For those who browsing stackoverflow instead of reading the documentation:
There is an option since v0.15.4 thanks to Oliver.

See:

- https://dmp.fabric8.io/#build-configuration
- https://dmp.fabric8.io/#start-configuration